# Create SqlSession from existing Connection directly

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis

I'm working with existing Java code wherein there is an existing JDBC connection pooling mechanism on deployed systems and an already existing setup to get JDBC connections. I'd like to leverage this to create a MyBatis SqlSession object without creating a Configuration, DataSource, and other things

I have code that already creates a `java.sql.Connection` object is given the desired resource. I'd like to leverage this and get that `SqlSession` object and use MyBatis from that point onwards.

I don't want MyBatis to manage connection pooling, determining which data source to use, etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't avoid creation of the `Configuration` object. It is used by the internal mybatis machinery like executors. But even if you could it will not help you much. In this case you will need to implement most of `Configuration` functionality yourself so it does not make sense to do that.

You main goal is to be able to use `SqlSessionFactory.openSession(Connection connection)` method. To do this you need to have `SqlSessionFactory`. The easiest way for you is to create `Configuration` like it is descried in mybatis [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html#sqlSessions):

```
TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();

Environment environment = new Environment("development", transactionFactory, dataSource);

Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);

// set properties to configuration here

SqlSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();
SqlSessionFactory factory = builder.build(configuration);
```

Now if your connection pool does implement `DataSource` you use it directly to create environment. If it does not you need to create an adapter around your pool which implements `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Comment: For anyone else in this situation, I got past this issue by doing it like @Roman Konoval mentions above. Specifically, explicitly creating the JdbcTransactionFactory object, an environment object and a Configuration object. However, I create a DataSource from an OracleDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to Roman's above, but I needed to create an Oracle datasource. For various reasons, the connection needs to be created using the Class.forName type sequence

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//yadayada";
String username = "myusername"; 
String password = "mypassword";
OracleDataSource oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSource();
oracleDataSource.setURL(connectionString);
oracleDataSource.setPassword(password);
oracleDataSource.setUser(username);
environment = new Environment("dev",transactionFactory,oracleDataSource);
configuration = new Configuration(environment);
configuration.addMappers("MyMybatisMapper");
sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
return sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
```

What I was missing was the OracleDataSource object.